# Externalizable: Serialisation with Gson

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I'm using `Gson` to serialize a `class` called `User.class` which extends `Externalizable`

```
public class User implements Externalizable {

    String username = "testname";        

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {}

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
      out.writeObject(username);
    }
}
```

The output in the file is

```
{
   user: {}
}
```

instead of

```
{
   user: "testname"
}
```

Comment: how are you serializing the object? If it's a simple pojo just add getter and setter for the properties you want to be serialized. No need to implement Externalizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
gson.toJson(new User(), System.out);
```

generates the following output:

```
{"username":"testname"}
```

using

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Why do you expext **user**:"testname" instead of **username**:"testname"?

Comment: Oh now it worked. I accedentely left ".excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()" when I initialized Gson. How would I prevent that normal variables in the class get serialized now? Shoud i use transient?

Edit: it actually returns {"username":"testname"} because of the username variable. the writeExternal doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the User name to the User Object. Make sure it is attached to the object.

Add a constructor and change the class like the following:

```
private String username;

public User(){
 this.username = "testuser";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor like this:

```
   public User(String username) {
    this.username = username;
     }
```

Create a method named `getUsername()`:

```
  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
    }
```

And here is your code:

```
   @Override
   public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
     out.writeObject(username);
   }
```

For more info take a look at this [example](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-externalizable-example)